# AppFabric monitoring issue, events won't travel from ASStagingTable to ASWcfEventsTable

Tags: sql-server, wcf, appfabric

I'm trying to get AppFabric monitoring to work but I'm stuck here. Events are being inserted into the ASStagingTable but they don't propagate to the ASWcfEventsTable. They do if I manually run the ASImportEvents sp.

I use SQL server 2008 worksation edition on Windows Server 2008R2. I've verified that the AppFabric Event Collection Service is running (but I guess if it wasn't there wouldn't be any records in the staging table) and SQL Server Agent is running. When I created the database (during the AppFabric configuration) I logged in with SQL server authentication and in the connection string I use are the same credentials. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I just found out that my Sql Server Agent error log is filled with entries with the following message:
[298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'CS1\Administrator', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved it! :) The problem whas that AppFabric's configuration wizzard sets the owner of the jobs in SQL Server Agent to the user that you are currently logged in as instead of the user you connect with to the database?! I changed the owner of the jobs to sa and now everything works.

Comment: in my scenario, SQL Server Agent was not turned on (as I dont always have it setup to be on).... so if your events arent showing up in the AppFabric Dashboard, check to make sure that the SQL Server Agent is running...